# Why is the duality gap zero for non convex quadratic programming with a single constraint?

Tags: duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

From what I read here [Convex Optimization, Appendix B](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) and [Perfect Duality §2.3](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/relaxations.pdf), strong duality holds for quadratic programs of the form:
$$
\min_x x^\top Ax+x^\top a+\alpha \ni x^\top Bx+x^\top b+\beta\le 0
$$

I have some trouble understanding why.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the generalized trust region problem. And in fact, one needs a minor assumption to guarantee strong duality. This is discussed in the paper 
         author      = "T.K. Pong and H. Wolkowicz",
     TITLE = {The generalized trust region subproblem},
   JOURNAL = {Comput. Optim. Appl.},
  FJOURNAL = {Computational Optimization and Applications. An International
              Journal},
    VOLUME = {58},
      YEAR = {2014},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {273--322},
      ISSN = {0926-6003},
   MRCLASS = {90C20 (90C26 90C55)},
  MRNUMBER = {3201963},
       DOI = {10.1007/s10589-013-9635-7},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10589-013-9635-7},

Essentially this is a hidden convex problem. The fact that the objective and constraint are quadratic means that the dual essentially enforces the Hessian to be positive semidefinite.